# I tried to filter null values.But,TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's a kata in codewars.There're an array of arrays.If you sort the arrays by their length,you will see,that their length-values are consecutive.But one array is missing.I tried to write a method, that return the length of the missing array.
My method can get the true length of the missing array,but I get an error message about null value.Now,I have tried to  filter null values.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at getLengthOfMissingArray 
>        at begin
>       at it
>         at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:179:21
>       at Promise._execute
>       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
>       at new Promise
>       at describe
>               at Object.handleError
>           at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext

```
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arrayOfArrays) {
  var str=[];
  if (arrayOfArrays=="")
    return 0;
  var Long=arrayOfArrays.length;
  for(var i=0;i<Long;i++){
    if (arrayOfArrays[i]=="")
      return 0;
    else
      str.push(arrayOfArrays[i].length);
  }
  str.sort(function(a,b){return a>b?1:-1});
  var sum=0,n=str.length;
  var totol=((str[0]+str[n-1])/2)*(n+1);
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    sum=sum+str[i];
  }
  return totol-sum;
}
```

Comment: What is line 179?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have an answer.But youre code looks very complicated:

```
 var mainarray=[]; // your array containing arrays
var left=mainarray.map(typeof el=="object"?el.length:0).sort().reduce((num,length)=>num+1==length?num+1:num,-1)+1;//if your first array length is 1, -1 has to be replaced with 0.
```

Get every length, if its not an array the length is 0, then sort it ascending and count up. if theres a place missing, stay at that value.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/ribaxoveyo/edit?console

Comment: Your code is so clever and practical.Now I get more experienced with Arrow functions.I have to get more practice to get it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `!arrayOfArrays` instead of `arrayOfArrays==""`, like this...

```
function getLengthOfMissingArray(arrayOfArrays) {
  var str=[];
  if (!arrayOfArrays)
    return 0;
  var Long=arrayOfArrays.length;
  for(var i=0;i<Long;i++){
    if (!arrayOfArrays[i])
      return 0;
    else
      str.push(arrayOfArrays[i].length);
  }
  str.sort(function(a,b){return a>b?1:-1});
  var sum=0,n=str.length;
  var totol=((str[0]+str[n-1])/2)*(n+1);
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    sum=sum+str[i];
  }
  return totol-sum;
}
```

Comment: I have another question.I have tried like this:var a=[];if (a) console.log(ture) else console.log(false);  and its outcomes is true,why?

Comment: This is because you've created an empty array, which is an object, and therefore not null.

Comment: It is so ! I understand it after your explanation.Thanks a lot.